# How to map nested list to flat values

Tags: python

I`m trying to parse a spreadsheet with a header that looks something like this:
[image: header]

My problem is those nested keys below "Контрагент". I decided to parse it like this:

```py
['Дата',
 'Номер документа',
 'Дебет',
 'Кредит',
 ['Контрагент',
  ['Наименование', 'ИНН', 'КПП', 'Счет', 'БИК', 'Наименование банка']],
 'Назначение платежа',
 'Код дебитора',
 'Тип документа']
```

But now, I don`t really have an idea as how to map it to a flat list of values:

```py
['21.05.2021',
 '591324565436',
 '0.00',
 '526345428.99',
 'asdasd',
 '234525460140679',
 '77130100123412341',
 '302328105423534200000000280',
 '0445252345234974',
 'asdfsadfsd',
 'sdfghsfgdhfdghdfgh',
 '',
 'dfghfgdhfdgh']
```

Given these variables, I want a function to return following dict:

```py
{
    "Дата": "21.05.2021",
    "Номер документа": "591324565436",
    "Дебет": "0.00",
    "Кредит": "526345428.99",
    "Контрагент": {
        "Наименование": "asdasd",
        "ИНН": "234525460140679",
        "КПП": "77130100123412341",
        "Счет": "302328105423534200000000280",
        "БИК": "0445252345234974",
        "Наименование банка": "asdfsadfsd"
    },
    "Назначение платежа": "sdfghsfgdhfdghdfgh",
    "Код дебитора": "",
    "Тип документа": "dfghfgdhfdgh"
}
```

I've gone this far without realizing it'd be raising `IndexError` on the 3rd line:

```py
def map_to_schema(schema, data):
    for i, elem in enumerate(data):
        key = schema[i]
        if isinstance(key, list):
            if key[0] not in result:
                result[key[0]] = {}
            
            result[key[0]] |= {
                key[1][i-len(key)]: elem
            }
        else:
            result[key] = elem
```

What should I do? Maybe the structure for the schema isn't good enough? I really have no idea...

Comment: @MarkRansom Why? Yes :)
Flattening returns me a __flat__ list with key `Контрагент` at the same level as all other keys. How am I supposed to treat that? All the keys below that key are in the sub-dict? How would I know if it is a key for dict? That's not really what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway) for [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70481943/13855835)! This is essentially the same algorithm, using a for loop.

```py
def map(schema, s_length, row: list):
    # If len(row) was less then *true* schema length, it would have thrown StopIteration.
    # I ended up just extending row list by delta elements.
    if (delta := s_length - len(row)) > 0:
        row.extend([""] * delta)
    
    iter_row = iter(row)
    result = {}
    for key in schema:
        if isinstance(key, list):
            result[key[0]] = {}
            for sub_key in key[1]:
                result[key[0]][sub_key] = next(iter_row)
        else:
            result[key] = next(iter_row)
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary comprehension and an iterator:

```
headers = ['Дата', 'Номер документа', 'Дебет', 'Кредит',
           ['Контрагент',  ['Наименование', 'ИНН', 'КПП', 'Счет', 'БИК', 'Наименование банка']],
           'Назначение платежа', 'Код дебитора', 'Тип документа']
values = ['21.05.2021', '591324565436', '0.00', '526345428.99', 'asdasd', '234525460140679', '77130100123412341',
 '302328105423534200000000280', '0445252345234974', 'asdfsadfsd', 'sdfghsfgdhfdghdfgh', '',
 'dfghfgdhfdgh']

it = iter(values)

out = {k[0] if (islist := isinstance(k, list)) else k:
       {k2: next(it) for k2 in k[1]} if islist else next(it)
       for k in headers}
```

output:

```
{'Дата': '21.05.2021',
 'Номер документа': '591324565436',
 'Дебет': '0.00',
 'Кредит': '526345428.99',
 'Контрагент': {'Наименование': 'asdasd',
  'ИНН': '234525460140679',
  'КПП': '77130100123412341',
  'Счет': '302328105423534200000000280',
  'БИК': '0445252345234974',
  'Наименование банка': 'asdfsadfsd'},
 'Назначение платежа': 'sdfghsfgdhfdghdfgh',
 'Код дебитора': '',
 'Тип документа': 'dfghfgdhfdgh'}
```

Comment: Thanks! I would like it to be a common `for` loop though

Comment: @Shmookoff you can do exactly the same with a for loop, give it a try and let me know if you don't manage

Comment: Would it be okay if I accepted my own answer?

Comment: Sure, this is your question, pick the answer you think is the best ;)